# how do I make it so my mobile responsive works on my web page?

Tags: css, mobile, position, toggle

I am trying to make my page mobile responsive but something is off. I had to change position of my nav-menu from absolute to relative for nav menu to go to the  right top corner but now im having issues with the responsive part as well as the collapse of menu.  i have been in tutorial hell trying to understand relative and absolute. I thought I had it but this proves i do not

```
 /* make for mobile*/
.mobile-nav-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 9998;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    outline: none !important;
    line-height: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
}
.mobile-nav-toggle i {
    color: #ffff;
}
.mobile.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 55px;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
   

The rest of the script :
  



  body {
    font-family: "open sans",sans-serif;
    background-color: #040404;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
}

body::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    background: #040404;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px){
    body::before {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
}

a {
    color: #18d26e;

}

a:hover {
    color: #18d26e;
    text-decoration: none;
}



h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: "Railewa", sans-serif;
}

/*==========Header=======*/

#header {
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 997;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#header * {
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;

}

#header h1 {
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "poppins",sans-serif; 
    
}


#header h1 a,
#header h1 a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}

header h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

#header h2 span {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #18d26e;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}

#header h2 span:hover {
    color: #ffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff28f4;
    padding-bottom: 6px;

}

#header .social-links {
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
}


#header .social-links a {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.1);
    color: #ffff;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-right: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

#header .social-links a:hover {
    background: #18d26e;

}

/*make it resposive*/
@media (max-width:992px) {
    #header h1 {
        font-size: 36px;
    }
    #header h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    #header .social-links {
        margin-top: 15px;

    }

    #header .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestion to your previous question and work from there? I don’t understand why you have to make the navbar relative.

Comment: I did the solution to the previous question fixed why I couldnt get it to go into the right top corner. but after changing the position the responsive part wont work

Comment: I didnt understand either but I couldnt get my nav bar positioned properly without changing it